# jqgrid formatter not working and no response

Tags: jqgrid

i have a js file and the function name called viewLineBtn.

in my server code, i have created a list of object

```
    List<GridModelClass> addmodelResult = new List<GridModelClass>();

    addmodelResult.Add(new GridModelClass { name = "AddTestApprove", label = "Approve", width = "40", hidden = false, formatter = "viewLineBtn" });
```

however, the viewLineBtn can not be recognize. How to solve it?

Comment: jQGrid's formatters are Javascript functions that you declare and they are called when the data in the grid is populated on the front-end. The parameters for the jQGrid formatter functions is very specific too.  Reference [Custom Formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter).  Custom formatters have nothing to do with server code so far as I know.

Comment: i have add the formatter = "viewLineBtn" in my list, and there are a function viewLineBtn in my javascript.

Comment: Post up your Javascript for us to review then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you returns `colModel` as JSON data return from the server. As the result you have `formatter` property which have the type `string` (like `formatter: "viewLineBtn"`) instead of function (like `formatter: viewLineBtn`, where `viewLineBtn` defined before as a function).

To fix the problem you can change how you defined formatter function. Instead of the usage

```js
function viewLineBtn (cellValue, options, rowObject) {
   // do something here
   return htmlFragmentOfCell;
}
```

you should use

```js
$.extend($.fn.fmatter, {
    viewLineBtn: function (cellValue, options, rowObject) {
       // do something here
       return htmlFragmentUsedInCell;
    }
});
```

In the case you can use `formatter: "viewLineBtn"` in `colModel`.

I would recommend you to define always [custom unformatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter#unformatting) (`unformat` property) if you defines [custom formatter](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:custom_formatter). To do this in case of usage string value of `formatter` you should define unformatter in the following way:

```js
$.extend($.fn.fmatter, {
    viewLineBtn: function (cellValue, options, rowObject) {
       // do something here
       return htmlFragmentUsedInCell;
    }
});
$.extend($.fn.fmatter.viewLineBtn, {
    unformat: function (cellValue, options, elem) {
        // do something here
        return htmlFragmentFromDomElem;
    }
});
```